# methodology [reposync?] for updating offline linux servers?

Tags: repository, internet, software-updates

having servers that do not have an internet connection, what is the proper method for getting all necessary rpms so that a `yum update` does not fail because of dependency problems?

Is there any other way than using `reposync` on an internet connected computer that is registered to repositories, and simply having to deal with every rpm from all repositories that you may have some software from?  In my case that is currently rhel-8 and epel-8 and rpmfusion-free.

*I know how to create a local repository on a linux system, it's a matter of getting all the rpms and intermediate versions of rpms to guarantee a successfull yum update from a clean install from dvd from rhel-8.7-x86_64-dvd.iso.  Reposync'ing 5 repo's in total in entirety which will amount to some 100gb of download, just doesn't seem right*

Comment: My usual approach is to nominate one server as the yum server, have it reposync all the useful repos down to it, and then just have the remaining servers in the organisation point at this nominated server.  Is that approach possible in your situation ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update a disconnected CentOS system from a list of installed RPMs?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/439841/how-to-update-a-disconnected-centos-system-from-a-list-of-installed-rpms)

Comment: I have servers in a lab that has no internet connection nor have a network connection to any computer that does have an internet connection.  So it's a matter of transferring all needed rpms via usb drive.

Comment: @ron are you working in an air-gapped environment, or is information allowed to *leave* the offline computer on a USB drive?

Comment: yes air-gapped, per definition at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_gap_(networking)

Comment: only method of data transfer is via cd/dvd or usb disk

Comment: It's not about the *method*, but about the direction: Are you allowed to transport files from the air-gapped computer to the computer connected to the internet, by *any* means?

Answer (score 0):

> air-gapped, per definition at en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_gap_(networking)

Well, what's the question then? You're not allowed to carry out information on what is installed on your air-gapped machine to the outside world.

So, you **cannot** be able to selectively only download the packages you need, since you're not allowed to have that information on the downloading computer.

Hence, you need a full download of all the packages that you *might* ever need.